# moving files with folder to new folder in bash

Tags: bash

lets say we have something like a bunch of file from
`find development/js -name "*.js"`

it returns something like

```
development/js/folder1/*.js
development/js/folder2/*.js
```

that we need to move to

```
# as you can see folder 1 & 2 is the same but diffrent folder
production/js/folder1/*.js
production/js/folder2/*.js
```

how can we move files in bash like above?

thanks!

edit* heres what im upto

```
#!/bin/bash
devel_file_js=`find ../../development/js -name "*.js"`
production_folder=`../../production/js`
for i in $devel_file_js; 
do 
    mv #hmm
done
```

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
dev_folder="../../development/js";
production_folder="../../production/js"

for old_location in $(find $dev_folder -name "*.js") 
do 
    new_location=$(echo ${old_location/${dev_folder}/${production_folder}/})
    new_dirname=$(dirname ${new_location})

    echo "Moving ${old_location} to ${new_location}"

    # Create folder if not exists
    if [[ ! -d ${new_dirname} ]]
    then
        mkdir -p ${new_dirname}
    fi

    # mv ${old_location} ${new_location}
done
```

Comment: error line 7. wew that was complicated, how does the ${} work?

Comment: works just fine! but the mkdir still buggy, cant work when its in a recursive folder, olny one correct?

Comment: Nice, sorry for the -p missing option. For line 7, it replace the string by the result for the matching pattern as follows : ${<variable name>/<pattern to replace>/<string to replace with>/}

Answer (score 0):

You mean like 'mv' :P

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_mv.htm

Comment: yup but im confuse with logic or the preserving a folder name. what i have in mind is use regex and search for the development/js change it with production/js or something like that.